# Is there a SDK for 2D games that will deploy to PC, Flash and Android?

Tags: 2d, android, flash

Is there such thing as an SDK or toolset that can produce Windows, Flash, and Android executables from the same source? Something like "write once, run in all three platforms?"

Comment: Excellent question. Exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unity3d exports to android and will export to flash 11 swf.  It can be made to to do 2d, but its not its primary function.

http://haxe.org/  is also a possibility.

If you drop your flash requirement there are lots more :)

Comment: can you comment on what other ones are a possibility?

Comment: If by "Flash," the OP means "playable in a web browser," Unity has that covered without dropping the requirement--just refining it.

Answer (score 3):

Google just released an early version of PlayN that does just what you want (on the paper) : https://developers.google.com/playn/

It's too early to say if it's useful or what.

Comment: So did they realize that "forplay" is a silly name or is that something different?

Comment: I don't know but what I know is that lack of documentation and any demo to show what have been done with it is a serious failure.

Answer (score 2):

This is what Adobe AIR is for. Personally I wouldn't really recommend that approach though, because it's not really optimal for each platform (especially not for mobile). I would recommend use Flash to develop for desktop browsers, and then port to a mobile development tool like Corona SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) library, it supports building games that work on PC and Android, and there are some experiments to get it to work with html5 (using gwt) and to get it to run on iOS (using the avian jvm).

This library has support for buiding 2d and 3d games, you can search in the android market for some examples of games made with the library [libgdx on the android market](https://market.android.com/search?q=libgdx&so=1&c=apps)

Some nice examples of games made with libgdx are:

- jumping slime
- tap 'n' crash
- Apparatus

Answer (score 0):

[FlashPunk](http://flashpunk.net/) is a nice game framework. It's pretty good - there's also [Flixel](http://flixel.org/). Both are pretty great with 2D game drawing; there's many, many games out there made with these two.

Comment: This doesn't exactly address the question. These are Flash games libraries, so they can be useful on all platforms Flash can be used on, but you didn't mention that part.